# Is this a BCNF violation?

Tags: database-normalization, bcnf

I read oodles of examples stating that 3NF is BCNF as long as there are no overlapping candidate keys...

Given:

```
R(a,b,c,d,e,f)
a,b,c -> d 
a,b,c -> e 
a,b,c -> f
```

so, a,b,c is the only candidate key.
So far it's BCNF.

Now, I add the FD f-> c , which is non-prime -> prime ***but*** I still don't have overlapping candidate keys.

Am I back to 3NF or am I still in BCNF?

Comment: But if you add f->d then: What are the CKs? And is it in 3NF? (What is a definition?) And are there overlapping CKs? And it is in BCNF? (What is a definition not using 3NF?) Why do you ask "Am I back to 3NF"? Show your work determining that. If you can't do it, post a question asking about where you are stuck in applying a definition. See hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Also if you were "still in BCNF" then you would still be in 3NF.

Answer (score 3):

If you add a new FD then you have to redetermine the CKs, which attributes are prime & non-prime, whether it's in 3NF, whether there are overlapping CKs & whether it's in BCNF.

We have a new given cover that has one more FD. (If we want all the FDs that now hold then we must reapply Armstrong's axioms. If we want a minimal cover for the new cover then we must calculate it.) Applying a definition of CK and/or an algorithm to find CKs we have CKs {a,b,c} & {a,b,f}. The non-prime attributes are d & e.  Applying a definition of 3NF, eg that every non-prime attribute is non-transitively functionally dependent on every CK, we have 3NF. There are overlapping CKs, so we might not have BCNF. Applying a definition of BCNF, eg that every determinant of a non-trivial FD is a superkey, we notice f->c is not out of a superkey, so we don't have BCNF.